# html5 pdf file embeded in iframe can not scroll in ios

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, safari

I have a iframe for showing text and pdf file. Its work perfectly in chrome, ie and mozilla. But i try to load the same in safari in ipad. pdf cant scroll. 
Attached code for the same.

```css
.docviewer-wrapper{
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container docviewer-wrapper">
  <iframe id="docvieweriframe" src="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"></iframe>
 </div>
```

Please help me.

Comment: A common know issue in ipads and iphones

Answer (score 0):

Try giving height and width to docviewer-wrapper class

Answer (score 0):

`iframe`, `object`, `embed` has some issues with iOS devices which are reported on number of platforms. All you can do is use some third party alternative for iframe.
I have solved my problem with [PDF.js](https://github.com/shyammohankanojia/pdfjs_rails)

If you are trying this for rails [this article](https://gist.github.com/ziaulrehman40/23e55156571f57aeb3053c3b8ceff0d0) will help you integrating pdf.js in your rails application.

Comment: pdf.js has loads of performance issues on large PDFs